# Sanity not starting anymore, even though I'm in the right file

Tags: sanity

I'm making sure to type in `sanity start` in the right file pathway (for me its the `Website` folder). Its been working for me fine the past week and up till today, but not anymore. I'm worried I've messed with my Sanity files somehow, its my first time trying to use a backend so its possible I've done something I shouldn't have (I was having confusions around sanity client last night, and that my current sanity version didn't support my current react version). I think I remember trying to upgrade sanity through the terminal, but otherwise I don't remember making any other changes. I'm currently having a big issue trying to fetch data from the backend, so that's been a whole thing too.

This is the whole message I'm getting in the command prompt:

```
@sanity/core not installed in current project
Project-specific commands not available until you run `sanity install`

Error: Command "start" is not available outside of a Sanity project context.
Run the command again within a Sanity project directory, where "@sanity/core"
is installed as a dependency.
    at _.runCommand (C:/Users/kiras/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/@sanity/cli/bin/sanity-cli.js:3608:1340)
    at t.exports (C:/Users/kiras/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/@sanity/cli/bin/sanity-cli.js:1980:2422)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my first comment so I apologize if I'm not following some standard that StackOverFlow-culture has.

I got the same error as you, as shown below.

```
Error: Command "start" is not available outside of a Sanity project context.
Run the command again within a Sanity project directory, where "sanity"
is installed as a dependency.
    at CommandRunner.runCommand (~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.12.1/lib/node_modules/@sanity/cli/lib/_chunks/cli-3984b311.js:17742:33333)
    at Object.runCli (~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.12.1/lib/node_modules/@sanity/cli/lib/_chunks/cli-3984b311.js:17745:2460)
```

Yesterday everything was fine but today, Sanity was not working. I was in the right file and directory, and my JSON package was formatted properly as well. I tried installing and deleting many things but nothing worked. I ran this command in the **studio** directory:

```
sanity install
```

After that prompt, I got the following:

```
The `@sanity/core` module is not installed in current project
Project-specific commands not available until you run `npm install`
? Package manager to use for installing dependencies? npm
```

Then... I got a ton of "**npm WARN deprecated**" warnings but then I tried:

```
sanity start
```

and it worked? I hope this helps, goodluck!

If this doesn't work, make sure you have the following:

1. **Scripts** are **Correct** in studio/package.JSON

   "scripts": {
   "start": "sanity start",
   "build": "sanity build"
   },
2. If you accidentally deleted some JSON file, you can use:

   npm i

to get it back, I made that mistake but make sure you're in the proper directory (web or studio).

Apologies for the long response, but this should work, a lot of the responces gave the same repetitive answer ("cd into sanity folder by writing cd sanity and then sanity start") and it frustrated me seeing the same thing 715,143,763 times lol

Good luck!